# Compact Framework Picture Box Image Problem

Tags: graphics, compact-framework

I have two picture boxes on a .net compact framework form.

Both picture boxes have their image set to a .png.

My problem is that when I compile or run the application, one of the images appears "greyed-out" or like a shadow of the actual image.

What might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

In what context?  In the application or the designer?  If it's in the designer, does closing the form designer and re-opening it fix it?  If it's in the app, we need to see some code.